# How to add text to the body of a CasperJS thenOpen() POST request

Tags: javascript, http-post, casperjs

I need to write a script inside of datorama.com to access pardot.com.  Pardot does have an API that requires a request that has a request inside the body as

POST: https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3
message body: email=&password=&user_key=

Right now here is my code:

```
phantom.casperPath = casperPath;
phantom.injectJs(casperPath + "/bin/bootstrap.js");

var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
});

casper.start().thenOpen('https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3',{ 
    method: 'post',
    content: { 
        'text' : 'email=<myemail>&password=<password>&user_key=<userKey>'
    }
}, function(response) {
     this.echo(this.getHTML());
});

casper.run();
```

I can tell that it is getting through to the server because it is responding this.echo(this.getHTML()); "Login Failed" .  I am using the right email/password/user_Key because i am pulling that from the API Console for pardot and it is working there.... So I believe the issue is I am not setting the body of the request correctly.

So does anyone know a way to set the body on the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`casper.open()` or `casper.thenOpen()` don't understand the `content` setting. You probably wanted to use `data`:

```
casper.start()
    .thenOpen('https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3', { 
        method: 'post',
        data: 'email=<myemail>&password=<password>&user_key=<userKey>'
    }, function() { ... });
```

Don't forget to use `encodeURIComponent()` on the email, password and user key parameters if you build the string yourself.

You can also pass an object:

```
casper.start()
    .thenOpen('https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3', { 
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            email: '<myemail>',
            password: '<password>',
            user_key: '<userKey>'
        }
    }, function() { ... });
```

If you expect something else than HTML from the API, then you should use `casper.getPageContent()` instead of `casper.getHTML()`.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  I looked a bit more through the documentation because I swear I tried this.... but it is returning the API key for me!  So now I need to log in with the API key and parse the XML